# java rest web service using post

Tags: java

I am trying to do a java rest web service using "POST" method.My client part to invoke the web service is working proper.But i am facing difficulty in accessing the passed parameters by "POST" method.Any help would be appreciable.
Here is my client side

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String urlParameters = "param1=world&param2=abc&param3=xyz";

    String request = "http://localhost:8080/wsRevDash/rest/post/test";

    URL url = new URL(request);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);

    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

And here is my java rest web service method to access the parameters(unable to access).

```
   @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)


    public String getpostdata(@QueryParam("param1") String param1,@QueryParam("param2") String param2)
    {

        JSONObject jObjDevice = new JSONObject();

         jObjDevice.put("Hello",param1);
         return jObjDevice.toJSONString();

     }
```

When i run,I am getting 
{"Hello":null} as json string instead of {"Hello":"world"}.Getting null means it is unale to access the passed parameters.Please do help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@QueryParam** like shown below.

```
public String getpost( @QueryParam("param1") String param1,
                        @QueryParam("param2") String param2){
   // Access both param below
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data using POST request is quite straightforward.

Instead of `conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);` you'll have to use `DataOutputStream` to send data

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("param1", "hello");
    params.put("param2", "world");

    JSONObject myJSON = new JSONObject(params);

    System.out.println(myJSON);

     byte[] postData = myJSON.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

     int postDataLength = postData.length;

    String request = "http://localhost:8080/wsRevDash/rest/post/test";

    URL url = new URL(request);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));

    //Try with Resources Example, just giving you an option
    // try (DataOutputStream wr = new
    // DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()))
    // {
    // wr.write(postData);
    // }

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(postData);
}
```

**Note:** You're sending `application/json` header in your request but I don't see a JSON in your code. It is advisable to send useful headers only

You can convert `HashMap` directly to `JSONObject` like,

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(params);
```

But this only works for `Map<String, String>`

To access the parameter in webservice, you'll have to accept `JSONObject` instead of accepting `Map<String, String>`.

```
public String getpost(JSONObject params) throws JSONException
{
    if(params.has("param1"))
        System.out.println(params.getString("param1"));

    if(params.has("param2"))
        System.out.println(params.getString("param2"));

    //IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC HERE AND THEN RETURN STRING
    return "your_return string";
}
```

Comment: Thank u for sharing the code.But what changes i have to do in my web method?

Comment: Instead of `conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);` you'll have to use `DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(postData);` to send data

Comment: I am unable to access the parameter.Here is my web method.                     
 public String getpostdata(@QueryParam("param1") param1,String@QueryParam("param2") String param2)
     {
               
      JSONObject jObjDevice = new JSONObject();
       
       jObjDevice.put("Hello",param1);
       return jObjDevice.toJSONString();
      
         }                                                                                                                While returning json it displays{"Hello":null}  instead of{"Hello":"a"}.Please suggest for any changes.

Comment: Are you sending JSON to your web service? See my updated code.

Comment: I updated my code.Now i am unable to access the parameter.Please suggest for any changes.